# Gram-Schmidt pan-sharpening in open source Python

Tags: python, raster, open-source-gis, pansharpening

I am looking to use the Gram-Schmidt pan-sharpening method in Python but I can't find any libraries that have this as an option. I found this, but I don't understand where to even go after reading it https://www.int-arch-photogramm-remote-sens-spatial-inf-sci.net/XL-1-W1/239/2013/isprsarchives-XL-1-W1-239-2013.pdf

I know you can do this in ArcGIS but I am trying to do everything open source.

Comment: I see in your cited report that the method has been patented by KODAK ~ https://patents.google.com/patent/US6011875A/en  The method is available in commercial software ESRI/ENVi, but I couldn't find any reference in open source software or libraries (GRASS/QGIS/SAGA/GDAL/orfeo/mapbox) so wondering whether that's because some fee is required...

Comment: ohhh maybe so, that would make sense.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that the patent expired in 2018, so that would not be a problem anymore.

Comment: An issue is opened in GDAL, for anyone who wants to contribute: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/5286

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever got an answer for this, but I found the [R package *fusionImage*](https://github.com/pacoalonso/fusionImage) to be a useful tool for pansharpening. Not Python per se, but open-source nonetheless. I believe it was released shortly after your question was first posted.